# Returning millisecond representation of datetime in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using Python, I'm storing a date & time as datetime.datetime into GAE. Is there a way to get the value of the date time in milliseconds as opposed to the fully formatted string version?

Based on the docs for datetime.datetime, I don't see any native methods on the date time class that does this.
http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-datetime.html

The original date value is stored this way:

```
date_time_float = 1015182600   #some date as timestamp
date_time_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time_float);
```

When I pull the data from the store, it is of type:

```
type(exported_date_time) # type: datetime.datetime
```

There's strftime to convert into a string representation but what I'm looking for is to convert 'exported_date_time' to milliseconds.

Comment: Couldn't you just grab the unix time stamp and multiply by 1000?

Comment: @agf Your answer is exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the seconds since the epoch:

```
date_time_secs = time.mktime(datetimeobj.timetuple())
```

or for the whole thing in miliseconds

```
date_time_milis = time.mktime(datetimeobj.timetuple()) * 1000 + datetimeobj.microsecond / 1000
```

or similar.

Comment: time.mktime's argument is 'struct_time or full 9-tuple which expresses the time in local time, not UTC'. How do you convert datetime.datetime into it?

Comment: @agf In the doc, the notation ``datetime.timetuple()`` means that **timetuple()** is a method of an instance of the class **datetime** (of the module **datetime**); in addition, **mktime()** returns a Unix time, a float. Moreover, for Dan, **date_time_object** is an instance of **datetime.datetime**. Then the expression must be: ``unixtime = time.mktime(date_time_object.timetuple())``

Comment: @agf I had written a confusing comment , I deleted it. And I didn't see your answer before my new comment. I understand now: you were considering ``datetime.timetuple()`` as generic representation of an _instance.timetuple()_ notation, as it is practiced in the docs. But I think that the use of this generic representation must be restricted to the docs, not used in real codes, otherwise it's confusing. You corrected and that's better. But IMO , the remaining name **date_time_object** for what is a float is still a flaw

Comment: OK. I should renew the page before posting..... eeeerr, by the way... These names are no more hardly incorrect, but they are still incoherent, i think....